# WordPress ajax successfully login but it's not set current user?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

```
function ajax_signon () {
    check_ajax_referer('mbx-nonce', 'security');
    $user = wp_signon();
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'userId' => -1,
            'loggedIn' => false,
            'message' => __('Wrong username or password.')
        ));
    } else {
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
        echo json_encode(array(
            'userId' => $user->ID,
            'loggedIn' => true,
            'message' => __('Login successful')
        ));
    }
    exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_signon', 'ajax_signon');
```

I have two site first in react and second in WordPress. I'm trying to login with WordPress. but both domain are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Set Proper login detail in your $user = wp_signon();

Like This:

```
//$_POST["user_email"] = 'admin';
//$_POST["user_password"] = '123456';

$user_login     = esc_attr($_POST["user_email"]);
$user_password  = esc_attr($_POST["user_password"]);

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $user_login;
$creds['user_password'] = $user_password;
$creds['remember'] = true;

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

Then set/use wp_signon for login like this:

```
$user_id = $user->ID;

wp_set_current_user($user_id);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
```

Other Method(direct login without password):

set user id like:

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id];
```

Then

```
wp_set_current_user($user_id);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
```

One more thing replace

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_signon', 'ajax_signon');
```

To

```
add_action('wp_ajax_signon', 'ajax_signon');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_signon', 'ajax_signon');
```

Comment: If you don’t provide $credentials, wp_signon uses the $_POST variable (the keys being “log”, “pwd” and “rememberme”).

Comment: If you set correct user_id on wp_set_current_user($user_id);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); wp accept logging.

Comment: How to get user_id : Open wp_user table and get ID and set anyway on wp_set_current_user($user_id); wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);  Wp login will work properly.